# Merge tags [file-upload] and [upload]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Just noticed there are two tags for basically the same thing:

- [file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-upload) has <strike>8441</strike> 21,691 questions, <strike>47 followers</strike> 142 watchers, and synonyms [upload-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upload-file), [fileuploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileuploader).

> a method or action of transferring a file from a client to a server.

- [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upload) has <strike>4961</strike> 11,428 questions, <strike>28 followers</strike> 66 watchers, and the synonym [uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uploads).

> Upload refers to the sending of data from a local system to a remote system such as a server or another client with the intent that the remote system should store a copy of the data being transferred, or the initiation of such a process

I can't see a benefit in having these distinct, so it seems to make sense that [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upload) should be changed to a synonym of [file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-upload)?

Since it has an existing synonym, it can't be suggested in the usual manner.

---

Another alternative might be to have a clear definition on the [upload tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/upload/info) stating that it is for the general concept of uploading (if that's a valid question area), and that the tag file-upload is for specific uploading files.

(Though perhaps such a general concept tag should be upload*ing* instead?)

Comment: [tag:upload] is the process, while [tag:file-upload] is one of the things you can do with uploading. I don't think they are the same, it is just another proof that we need parent/child relations in tags...

Comment: I don't see the value in that distinction. What can you upload that isn't a file?

Comment: (I do agree in general with the need for parent/child tag relations though.)

Comment: The other way around would make more sense (if one should do it at all). Not all uploads are file-uploads. E.g. your program could work with structured data types and your server can understand those. Files typically are flat.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think upload should be changed to a synonym of file-upload. What about questions not tied to the process of uploading a file, but in regards to upload *speed*?

Upload speed plays a significant role in general internet activity (requests), and can impact things like media streaming which is not tied to file-uploading.

Since uploading/downloading is simply sending *data* to/from a remote server I don't think it should be tied to "files".

Comment: _"What about questions [] in regards to upload speed?"_ - tag them [tag:upload-speed];
_"things like media streaming"_ - tag them [tag:media-streaming];
I guess the question becomes: is it possible to have an on-topic question about the concept of uploading that should not have a more specific tag instead?

Comment: @PeterBoughton - I suppose the aregument really boils down to, "should generic tags be allowed?". "upload" is generic, it could be used for "upload-speed" or "file-upload". Why would you make it a synonym of one over the other?

Comment: Yeah... is there a way to require a tag to be disambiguated? So if someone tried to enter "upload" they are prompted "please use file-upload or upload-speed or [other related]"?

Comment: @PeterBoughton - not that I'm aware of. What I've seen is in various "generic" type tags they put a comment in the description that says "you should probably use something more specific like xxx or yyyy". However, IMO, that doesn't seem to work very well. (people tend not to read tag descriptions)

Comment: Can you give an example of an uploading speed question that would be on-topic at Stack Overflow?

Comment: @TylerH Programming an application capable of networking that shows slow uploading speed? Then asking for help about socket programming, buffering, etc.

Comment: @Sebastian Wow, bit of necromancy! Your suggestion is still covered by a [file-upload] tag, in my opinion. Such a tag covers implementing a process, which can include showing details on the speed. We also have a [performance] tag that is heavily used to cover specific concerns about file upload performance.

Comment: @Would a multiplayer game upload *files*? Perhaps in this example one would not call it upload at all any longer, but upstream networking speed.